# Type Error when updating state with complex nested structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm encountering a type error while trying to update the state of my React components. The error message is as follows:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(prevItem: Item | null) => { tags: (AddNewTagProps | null | undefined)[]; id: string; image?: string[] | undefined; dueDate?: Date | undefined; comments: Comment[]; description: string; title: string; } | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Item | null>'.
  ...
```

I have a complex nested state structure that involves Item, Column, and Tag interfaces. Here are the basic type definitions:

```
interface Item {
    id: string;
    tags: Tag[];
    // Other properties...
}

interface Tag {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    color?: string;
}

interface Column {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    items: Item[];
}
```

In a specific button's onClick handler, I'm trying to update the state as follows:

```
setSelectedItem((prevItem) => {
    if (!prevItem) return null;
    return {
        ...prevItem,
        tags: [...prevItem.tags, newTag],
    };
});

setColumns((prevColumns) => {
    const updatedColumns = prevColumns.map((col) => {
        const updatedItems = col.items.map((item) =>
            item.id === (selectedItem?.id || '')
                ? {
                      ...item,
                      tags: [...item.tags, newTag],
                  }
                : item
        );

        return {
            ...col,
            items: updatedItems,
        };
    });
    return updatedColumns;
});
```

However, TypeScript is giving me a type error related to the tags property. It seems that TypeScript is having trouble reconciling the types, particularly with tags

How can I resolve this type error when updating my state with a complex nested structure? Is there a better way to handle these type issues when working with nested state updates?

React version: "^18.2.0"
TypeScript version: "^5.1.6"

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example